# How to correctly assign primary key to DataTable in c#?

Tags: c#, datatable, primary-key

I have a `DataTable` that it populated with job titles. I am trying to set the `JobTitle` column as the primary key but cannot seem to get it to work. Where am I going wrong?

I have used both code from StackOverflow and the Microsoft site to no avail.

```
public class AutoEnrolTable
{
    public DataTable autoEnrolDT { get; private set; }
    private Dictionary<int, string> dictJobTitles;
    private Dictionary<int, string> dictAssessments;

    public AutoEnrolTable()
    {
        autoEnrolDT = new DataTable();
        dictAssessments = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        dictJobTitles = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        autoEnrolDT.Columns.Add("Job Title", typeof (string));
        SetAssessmentsDict();
        SetJobTitlesDict();
        SetAssessments();
        SetJobTitles();
        autoEnrolDT.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { autoEnrolDT.Columns["Job Title"] };
    }

    private void SetAssessmentsDict()
    {
        SqlStoredProcedure sp = new SqlStoredProcedure("GetAssessmentAndModule", DB.conStr);

        DataTable dt = sp.ExecuteAndReturnDataTable();

        foreach (DataRow assessment in dt.Rows)
        {
            int assessmentID = assessment.Field<int>("AssessmentID");
            string assessmentName = assessment.Field<string>("AssessmentName");
            dictAssessments.Add(assessmentID, assessmentName);
        }
    }

    private void SetJobTitlesDict()
    {
        SqlStoredProcedure sp = new SqlStoredProcedure("GetJobTitleAndDepartment", DB.conStr);

        DataTable dt = sp.ExecuteAndReturnDataTable();

        foreach (DataRow jobTitle in dt.Rows)
        {
            int adJobTitleID = jobTitle.Field<int>("AD_JobTitleID");
            string jobTitleName = jobTitle.Field<string>("JobTitleAndDepartment");
            dictJobTitles.Add(adJobTitleID, jobTitleName);
        }
    }

    private void SetAssessments()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> entry in dictAssessments)
        {
            autoEnrolDT.Columns.Add(entry.Value);
        }            
    }

    private void SetJobTitles()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> entry in dictJobTitles)
        {
            DataRow dataRow = autoEnrolDT.NewRow();
            dataRow["Job Title"] = entry.Value;
            autoEnrolDT.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain **"but cannot seem to get it to work"**

Comment: Ah, my apologies. The Job Titles column remains a column of the data table and not the primary key index.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. A datacolumn that is made a primary key will always remain a column in the datatable. What subsequent operation are you trying, that is failing? What is the exception?

Comment: Assuming that I understand the dataTable.PrimaryKey function correctly, after `autoEnrolDT.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { autoEnrolDT.Columns["Job Title"] };`, the Job Title column should no longet be a column in the table, but will be the row headers as an index?

Comment: I think you're getting confused between a data storage container and a device that performs visualization of data (such as a grid). Declaring a column to be a datatable's primary key will merely prevent you from inserting duplicate or null values into that column, and facilitate data lookup (effectively establishes a `Dictionary<pk_column_type, DataRow>`). It does nothing to alter the presentation of data in some visualizing control. DataTables do not have "row headers" - they're a collection of DataRow objects

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you for confirming this then. How would I go about setting one of the columns as the visual index of the table?

Comment: What's a "visual index" ? can you include a screenshot of something you think a "visual index" is?

Comment: Rather than 1, 2, 3 down the side, have text. [image](https://imgur.com/a/4jki2K9)